# Link out of a page viewer web part?

Tags: 2010, html, page-viewer-web-part

I created a webpage in HTML and CSS because I did not fee like dealing with branding or anything like that.  I placed this HTML page into a webpage viewer and everything seemed to be working...until I started testing.

In the page I have a link to a web based info path form that employees can fill out and submit, once submitted the form redirects them back to the homepage.  This all seemed to be working fine until I realized that it simply loaded the home page in the page viewer webpart/Iframe! so now it has a ribbon on top of a ribbon and just looks weird.

So my question is:
1) Is it possible to make a link in the Iframe/page viewer web part that will change the browser/page outside of the frame?
2) If so, where and how can I learn this syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Add target="_blank" to the link and it should open in a new tab/window.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what he wants. He needs to send a redirect / window.location from the child to the parent